# sql select with except in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got the item that i want to like this:

```
SELECT 
     ORDRE.NO_ORDRE
     ,ORDRE.CODE_CLIENT

  FROM [Soft8Exp_Client].[dbo].[ORDRE]  
      where DATEPART(YEAR,ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 2014
  and DATEPART(MONTH,ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 4
  and DATEPART(DAY,ORDRE.DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 29

 EXCEPT

  SELECT  
      [NO_ORDRE]     
      ,[CODE_CLIENT]   
  FROM [Soft8Exp_Client].[dbo].[LETTRE_VOIT]
    where DATEPART(YEAR,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 2014
  and DATEPART(MONTH,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 4
  and DATEPART(DAY,DATE_CLOTUR_REEL) = 29
```

now how can i put it into UPDATE command ?

```
   UPDATE [Soft8Exp_Client].[dbo].[ORDRE]
SET STATUS = 1
    WHERE ??
```

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to do. Do you want this?

```
 UPDATE [Soft8Exp_Client].[dbo].[ORDRE] o
 SET o.STATUS = 1
 FROM (
    -- Your query from the top of your question    
 ) t
 WHERE o.NO_ORDRE = t.NO_ORDRE AND o.CODE_CLIENT = t.CODE_CLIENT;
```